# Regular Expression and Hive

Tags: sql, regex, hadoop, hive

I'm trying to create a hive external table using org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.RegexSerDe for analysing comments. The sample rows are:

```
0   @chef/maintain fix the problem  2017-05-25 20:34:45  1  2017-05-25 20:34:27 0

6   ^ trailing comma is trolling you    2017-05-23 23:08:46 0   2017-05-24 04:40:42 1
```

This is my regex:

```
("input.regex" = “(d{1,5}\\s\\w+\\s\\.{19}\\.{1}\\s\\.{1}");
```

I am getting a null table and couldn't figure the regex.

Table definition:

order                 1,2,3,4...
comment               @chef/maintain fix the problem
comment_time          2017-05-25 20:34:45
merged                1 or 0
merged_time           2017-05-25 20:34:27
resolved              1 or 0

Can any one help on this?

Comment: You have a weird quote `“(` in your regex, not sure if that's a typo or you really have that in your code

Comment: Table defibition? Requested redults?

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex

```
(\\d)\\s+([^\\d{4}]*)\\s(\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}\\s\\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2})\\s+(\\d)\\s+(\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}\\s\\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2})\\s(\\d)
```